# How to add edit button to only some rows meeting specific condition in oracle apex report

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

i want to add edit button to some specific rows only in a oracle apex report.suppose i want an edit button only in those rows having job = manager.
after clicking that button i will be redirected to another page present in my application.please help regarding these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a column of type Display As Text, with Escape Special Characters set to No, defined in the report SQL something like:

```
 ...
 case when e.job = 'MANAGER' then
   q'[<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="redirect(']'
   || apex_page.get_url
        ( p_page => 123
        , p_items => 'P123_EMPNO'
        , p_values => e.empno
        )
   || q'[')" class="myButtonClass">]'
 end as edit_button
```

In this example, when clicked the button will redirect to page 123 of the same application and pass this row's `empno` value into item `P123_EMPNO'.

You can use the class attribute to apply classes for styling - you may want to use Universal Theme class names like 't-Button' for consistency.

Applied to your SQL from comment below:

```
SELECT apex_item.checkbox(1,empno,'UNCHECKED') " ",
       empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, comm,
       case when job = 'MANAGER' then
         q'[<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="redirect(']'
         || apex_page.get_url
              ( p_page => 123
              , p_items => 'P123_EMPNO'
              , p_values => empno
              )
         || q'[')" class="myButtonClass">]'
       end as edit_button
  from emp;
```

Comment: how can i add a column of type display as text , i mean in item creation display as text is there..

Comment: i have altered the table created a new column now where to put this query

Comment: No, don't create a new column in the table!  Just change the report's SQL query and add another column to that.

Comment: should i simply paste the above code in my existing report's sql code?

Comment: SELECT apex_item.checkbox(1,empno,'UNCHECKED') " ",
empno,
ename,
job,
hiredate,
sal,
comm from emp;

Comment: this is my current sql query for report

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Never "simply paste" anything: understand it first!

Comment: just checked edit button appeared where i wanted but still its not being redirected to another page when i click it

Comment: thanks a lot i made the required changes and its finally working